# How can I migrate an Aptana workspace between two installations

Tags: migration, aptana, workspace

I am in the process of migrating between two operating systems on the same computer.  This has got to the stage of being a multiboot system; both OS are Windows Vista.  The aim ultimately is to replace the old (and creaking) system with another Vista OS.  One is intended as a working system and the other as an experimental system where I can indulge in some of the hairier techniques I pick up on the web and elsewhere without unduly compromising the working system.

I now have data from the old system replicated in a separate disk partition so that it can be accessed from either OS.  Aptana Studio 3 is set up on both systems and I have successfully imported projects from one to the other.  However, one component missing from the process is the local history files, so that I cannot get back to previous versions of project files from the new installation.  I have discovered that these files are located in %WORKSPACE%.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.history, but have not found a way of accessing them from either installation.  Copying them across from either the data partition mentioned above or from the old OS doesn't appear to work, and anyway would defeat the object of being being able to access project files, including their histories, from either system.

What I am looking for is a way of migrating the Aptana workspace in the old system, complete not only with projects (which I have done and which works) but also with their local histories so that both Aptana installations can access them on completely equal terms.

I hope that makes sense.  Please bear in mind that I am an enthusiastic amateur rather than an IT professional; that may influence the range and depth of any advice that may be offered.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I would suggest a more complete version control system (git, for example) over relying on Aptana's local history. Aptana generally has new bugs with each release and I would hate for one of them to wipe your local history since you are obviously invested in it. Hope you find a solution.

Comment: Thanks, Sarah; I thought that might be the case.  I am now using Git, and I take your point.  The curious thing is that the local history files are still in place, but Aptana claims that the files in my projects have no local history.  Somehow the links between the two have been broken.  Given time I can work around that; at least the local history files are text files.